# making video calls through communicator from c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am new to c# application.I want to make a video call from office communicator using c# form application.I have heard about the communicator sdk and Lync. But not sure what to choose.
Can I get any help regaerding this?

Answer (score 0):

Office Communicator is now called Microsoft Lync.

To jump-start, you can [download the Lync SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=18898).

I think this [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2010/UNC306) will also help you start. (Which failed to load for me, so, Heads up)

As a motivation, have a look at [Scott Hanselman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6380/scott-hanselman)'s (Microsoft SVP) [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingLync2010SuperSimpleAutoAnswerVideoKioskWithFullScreen.aspx) post about how he designed `Super Simple Auto Answer Video Kiosk with Full Screen Capability`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Madushan : Thanks for the reply :) ! Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 SDK and Lync SDK,How are they different? Is the former for OC 2007 and latter for OC 2010.Having installed Oc 2007 and having Lync SDK,will that be a issue? The video talks about using Microsoft silverlight. Can the Lync SDK be used in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (.net 4 c#)? I am new to c#.

Comment: Using Lync SDK in my c# application, can I make a video call to the person who is using OC 2007?

Comment: I'm not sure about it.. I assume the remote person is on a different server than your's (given he is running a different version) and if 2 servers are federated to communicate, I assume, yes you can. But I can't be sure. Sorry.